# What is the output type from reflection in this code

Tags: c#, reflection

I have the following method:

```
public static class ReflectionHelper
{
    public static List<?> FindType<T>()
    {
        var A =
            from Assemblies in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().AsParallel()
            from Types in Assemblies.GetTypes()
            let Attributes = Types.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), true)
            where Attributes?.Length > 0
            select new { Type = Types };

        var L = A.ToList();

        return L;
    }
}
```

what is the type of the list?

if I do:

```
foreach (var l in L) { ... }
```

it works find and I can go through the types, but dev environment I'm using (Rider) will not provide a type.

Comment: It's an anonymous type, so you cannot directly use that type as a method return type.
In your specific case you can change it to:
select Types
And then the generic type would be Type (it would actually be List<Type[]>> unless you flatten it).

Comment: Can I get an explanation about the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an anonymous object with the single property

```
IEnumerable<Type> Types;
```

So, using `A.ToList()` gives you a list of the anonymous object, which you cannot return.

I think that rather than using `select new { Type = Types };`, you want to use `select Types;`

So:

```
public static List<Type> FindType<T>()
{
    var types =
        from ssembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().AsParallel()
        from type in ssembly.GetTypes()
        let attributes = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), true)
        where attributes?.Length > 0
        select type;

    return types.ToList();
}
```

Comment: The 'SelectMany' doesn't compile (I have done the 'select Types' change).